# What alternatives are there to useRef when reusing a modal for adding and editing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following react component for a Mantine-Modal that should allow adding and editing of "point in time"-entries.

```
const PointInTimeModal = ({title, onSubmit}:PointInTimeModalType) => {

  const [opened, { open, close }] = useDisclosure(false);

  return (
    <Modal opened={opened} onClose={close} title={title}>
      <PointInTimeForm onSubmit={onSubmit}}/>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

I would like to use it as follows in my timeline control component so that there is only one instance of this modal.

```
const TimelineControls = () => {

  return (
    <Group>
      <PointInTimeModal />
      <AddPointInTime />
      <EditPointInTime />
      <DeletePointInTime />
    </Group>
  )
}
```

Now I'm stuck on how to connect the controls to the modal. I would need to expose `open` to the Add- and Edit-Buttons. I've seen that `useRef` and `useImperativeHandle` could probably achieve this, but every tutorial always comes with the caveat that there is probably a better solution that I should take instead.

Unfortunately, none of the tutorials I saw pointed me towards said better solution, so I'm at a loss how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `useRef` and `useImperativeHandle` can be used for this, they are often not the preferred approach in React, especially for component communication. A more React-friendly solution involves using a combination of state and callbacks.

1. **Lift the State Up**: Move the state that controls the visibility of the modal to the parent component (`TimelineControls`). This way, you can control the modal's visibility from the parent component.
2. **Pass Down Callbacks**: Pass a callback function to `AddPointInTime` and `EditPointInTime` that they can call to open the modal.
3. **Prop Drilling for onSubmit**: Pass down the `onSubmit` function to `PointInTimeModal` through props.

Try this approach:

**Modified `PointInTimeModal`**

```
const PointInTimeModal = ({ title, onSubmit, opened, onClose }: PointInTimeModalType) => {
  return (
    <Modal opened={opened} onClose={onClose} title={title}>
      <PointInTimeForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

**Updated `TimelineControls`**

```
const TimelineControls = () => {
  const [modalOpened, setModalOpened] = useState(false);
  const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState("");
  const [onSubmit, setOnSubmit] = useState(() => () => {});

  const openModal = (title, onSubmitCallback) => {
    setModalTitle(title);
    setOnSubmit(() => onSubmitCallback);
    setModalOpened(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalOpened(false);
  };

  return (
    <Group>
      <PointInTimeModal
        title={modalTitle}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        opened={modalOpened}
        onClose={closeModal}
      />
      <AddPointInTime onOpen={() => openModal("Add Point", handleSubmitAdd)} />
      <EditPointInTime onOpen={() => openModal("Edit Point", handleSubmitEdit)} />
      <DeletePointInTime />
    </Group>
  );
};
```

**Add/Edit Components**

Make sure that `AddPointInTime` and `EditPointInTime` components receive an `onOpen` prop and call it when they need to open the modal. For example:

```
const AddPointInTime = ({ onOpen }) => {
  // ...
  return <Button onClick={onOpen}>Add Point</Button>;
};

const EditPointInTime = ({ onOpen }) => {
  // ...
  return <Button onClick={onOpen}>Edit Point</Button>;
};
```